# How to make space between two column items?

Tags: html, css

I want to display list of items in two columns. But there are less space between two column items. I want more space between. where should I change? I tried to add more pixel as padding. But it didn't work.

```css
#category{
  background: #062134;
  color: white;
  display: table;
  width:100%;
  font-size: 20px;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;

  -moz-box-align: center;
  -moz-box-pack: center;

  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
}

#category .column-title {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#category > div {
  display: table-row;
}

#category > div > div {
  display: table-cell;
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  padding-right: 50px;
   padding-left: 50px;

}

#category > div > div:first-child {
  padding-left: 5%;
  padding-right: 1%;

}


#category .column-title {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#category > div {
  display: table-row;
}

#category > div > div {
  display: table-cell;
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;

}

#category > div > div:first-child {
  padding-left: 5%;
  padding-right: 1%;
}

#category > div > div:nth-child(2) {
  padding-left: 1%;
  padding-right: 1%;
}

#category > div > div:nth-child(3) {
  padding-left: 1%;
  padding-right: 30%;
}

#category p {
    line-height: 300%;
}
#category input {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  background: #062134;
  /*border: 2px solid white;*/
  border-top: 2px solid white;
  border-right: 0;
  border-bottom: 2px solid white;
  border-left: 2px solid white;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  /*padding: 10px;*/
   color: white;
  height: 36px;
  text-indent: 10px;
}
#category button {
  float: left;
  background: #062134 10px 10px no-repeat;
  height: 40px;
  width: 70px;
  height: 40px;
  border-top: 2px solid white;
  border-right: 2px solid white;
  border-bottom: 2px solid white;
  border-left: 0;
  border-left: 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

/*.row-2 p {
    clear: left;
}*/
#category input:focus {
  outline: 0;
  background: #4D7EC9;
}

#category input:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.5em white;
}

#category button:hover {
  background-color: blue;
}

#category button:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

.list-of-resources {
  display: table;
}

.list-of-resources > div {
  display: table-row;
}

.list-of-resources > div > div {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 5px 0;
}

.list-of-resources > div > div:last-child {
  padding: 0 0 0 100px;
}

.list-of-resources a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

.list-of-resources a:hover {
  color: tomato;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
  #category > div > div {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 28%;
    padding-top: 50px;
  }

  #category > div > div:first-child {
    padding-left: 5%;
    padding-right: 1%;
  }

  #category > div > div:nth-child(2) {
    padding-left: 1%;
    padding-right: 1%;
  }

  #category > div > div:nth-child(3) {
    padding-left: 1%;
    padding-right: 5%;
  }
}


@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {


  #category > div > div {
    width: 90%;

    -webkit-flex: 1 6 20%;
           flex: 1 6 20%;
   -webkit-order: 3;
           order: 3;
  }

  #category > div > div:nth-child(2) {
    clear: both;
    padding-left: 5%;
    padding-top: 10px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="category">
        <div>
            <div class="column">
                <div class="column-title">Explore</div>
                    <div class="column-content list-of-resources">
                    <div>
                        <div><a href="#">Envato</a></div>
                        <div><a href="#">Themeforest</a></div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <div><a href="#">Themecurve</a></div>
                        <div><a href="#">Microsoft</a></div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <div><a href="#">Kreativeshowcase</a></div>
                        <div><a href="#">Google</a></div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <div><a href="#">Freebiescurve</a></div>
                        <div><a href="#">Yahoo</a></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you can add `width: Xpx;` in `.list-of-resources > div > div` for example==>  `.list-of-resources > div > div {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 5px 0;
  width: 500px;
}`

Comment: Your code is working...But When I put into mobile view,I wanted that the lists will go down..but in mobile view the lists are in same place.

Comment: i send you answers in an Answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Your code is working...But When I put into mobile view,I wanted that
>   the lists will go down..but in mobile view the lists are in same
>   place.

you can use this code

css

```
#category{
  background: #062134;
  color: white;
  display: table;
  width:100%;
  font-size: 20px;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;

  -moz-box-align: center;
  -moz-box-pack: center;

  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
}

#category .column-title {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#category > div {
  display: table-row;
}

#category > div > div {
  display: table-cell;
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  padding-right: 50px;
   padding-left: 50px;

}

#category > div > div:first-child {
  padding-left: 5%;
  padding-right: 1%;

}


#category .column-title {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#category > div {
  display: table-row;
}

#category > div > div {
  display: table-cell;
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;

}

#category > div > div:first-child {
  padding-left: 5%;
  padding-right: 1%;
}

#category > div > div:nth-child(2) {
  padding-left: 1%;
  padding-right: 1%;
}

#category > div > div:nth-child(3) {
  padding-left: 1%;
  padding-right: 30%;
}

#category p {
    line-height: 300%;
}
#category input {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  background: #062134;
  /*border: 2px solid white;*/
  border-top: 2px solid white;
  border-right: 0;
  border-bottom: 2px solid white;
  border-left: 2px solid white;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  /*padding: 10px;*/
   color: white;
  height: 36px;
  text-indent: 10px;
}
#category button {
  float: left;
  background: #062134 10px 10px no-repeat;
  height: 40px;
  width: 70px;
  height: 40px;
  border-top: 2px solid white;
  border-right: 2px solid white;
  border-bottom: 2px solid white;
  border-left: 0;
  border-left: 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

/*.row-2 p {
    clear: left;
}*/
#category input:focus {
  outline: 0;
  background: #4D7EC9;
}

#category input:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.5em white;
}

#category button:hover {
  background-color: blue;
}

#category button:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

.list-of-resources {
    width: 800px;
}

.list-of-resources #left
{
    float: left;
    width: 400px;
}

.list-of-resources #right
{
    float: right;
    width: 400px;
}

.list-of-resources a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

.list-of-resources a:hover {
  color: tomato;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
    .list-of-resources {
        width: 100%;
    }

    .list-of-resources #left
    {
        float: left;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .list-of-resources #right
    {
        float: left;
        width: 100%;
    }

}


@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {


  #category > div > div {
    width: 90%;

    -webkit-flex: 1 6 20%;
           flex: 1 6 20%;
   -webkit-order: 3;
           order: 3;
  }

  #category > div > div:nth-child(2) {
    clear: both;
    padding-left: 5%;
    padding-top: 10px;
  }
}
```

html

```
<div id="category">
        <div>

            <div class="column">
                <div class="column-title">Explore</div>
                <div class="column-content list-of-resources">
                 <div id="left">
                    <div><a href="#">Envato</a></div>
                    <div><a href="#">Themecurve</a></div>
                    <div><a href="#">Kreativeshowcase</a></div>
                    <div><a href="#">Freebiescurve</a></div>
                </div>
                <div id="right">
                    <div><a href="#">Themeforest</a></div>
                    <div><a href="#">Microsoft</a></div>
                    <div><a href="#">Google</a></div>
                    <div><a href="#">Yahoo</a></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

pic

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are you not allowed to use a `<table>`? I know that it's said that tables ***should not*** be used for laying our entire web pages, but there are certainly times that tables are completely appropriate for aligning items as you seem to be trying to display them. Then the `padding` within the `td` elements will affect the spacing between columns as will the `border-spacing` attribute.

---

If you insist on using the nested elements as you have them, the spacing you desire can be added in this area of your `.css` file.

```
.list-of-resources > div > div:last-child
{
    /* 100px is the value as it exists in your .css file. You'll have to make it larger as desired */
    padding: 0 0 0 100px;
}
```

You can change the padding using any of the accepted conventions:

```
padding: [top] [right] [bottom] [left];
padding: [top-bottom] [left-right];
padding-left: [padding];
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
.list-of-resources > div >div{
  padding: 10px;
}
```

Comment: I have changed the code to your code..but nothing changing..And when in mobile view I wanted that smal screen the lists will adjust with the "category" class ..but this one also not happening

Comment: padding top right bottom left; such as padding: 5px 0 5px 0; will definitely put space between your listing elements at top and bottom and nothing on the sides.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```css
.list-of-resources{
  width:100%
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Padding works, you just need to define it a bit more:

```
.list-of-resources > div > div { ((top))10px ((right))0 ((bottom))10px ((left))0}
```

Comment: I have changed the code to your code..but nothing changing..And when in mobile view I wanted that smal screen the lists will adjust with the "category" div class ..but this one also not happening

Comment: Might want to make this syntactically valid.